# Calculating the constant attached to the asymptotic complexity of heap and merge sorts

Tags: sorting, runtime, heap, constants, big-o

I programmed both a merge and a heap sort and calculated the runtime complexity, I am suppose to now find the constant c for merge and heap sort from the data I collected (c*(n*lg(n))). The following are the two graph formulas (from excel) of the number of elements (n) vs. runtime (seconds), how would I calculate the c constant? Any help will be appreciated! Thank you.

Heap:
y = 5E-12x2 + 2E-05x - 0.0561

Merge:
y = 9E-10x2 - 9E-05x + 2.0958

Answer (score 0):

The formulas you've given are polynomials of the form f(*n*) = *an*<sup>2</sup> + *bn* + *c* with constants *a*, *b*, and *c*. These aren't going to help you.

You need to fit an equation of the form f(*n*) = *an* lg(*n*) + *bn* + *c* to your data. Not a polynomial, but an equation with an *n* lg(*n*) term in it. The coefficient of that term is what you've been asked for. The linear (*b*) and constant (*c*) terms don't matter. Just the constant on the *n* lg(*n*) term since it grows the fastest.

Comment: XD I added the trendline but I don't see any way of adding an equation of that form...I guess I need to do some excel researching! But thanks!

Comment: I'm not an expert, but this may be beyond the power of Excel.

Comment: Yeah...it seems like that is the case...I am not sure how to go about this now...